# Kernel appears to have died on Jupyter notebook, julia 1.7.2

Tags: optimization, jupyter-notebook, julia

I'm running a julia kernel 1.7.2 in Jupyter notebook on Mac, but when I run the following code I get an error: `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

I have tried using `]` `build IJulia` but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Pkg.add("JuMP")
Pkg.add("Cbc")
using JuMP
using Cbc

model = Model(Cbc.Optimizer);
@variable(model, q[1:T] >= 0);
@variable(model, y[1:T] >= 0, Bin);
@variable(model, x[1:T] >= 0);
@objective(model, Min, sum( K*y[t] + h*x[t] for t in 1:T));

@constraint(model,[t = [1]]  , x[t] == x0     + q[t] - d[t]);
@constraint(model,[t = 2:T], x[t] == x[t-1] + q[t] - d[t]);

@constraint(model,[t = 1:T], q[t] <= M*y[t]);
```

I hope you can help. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I tried installing the Cbc in Julia REPL but it doesn't work.
I then ran the script in Julia in the terminal on Mac and got the following error:

[image]

Do you know how to fix this?

UPDATE:
I found out that the problem is that I have a new MacBook with an M1 chip. By **installing a version of julia meant for Intel or Rosetta**, it now works!

Comment: `Cbc` takes on slower machines like 5-10 minutes to compile. Most likely this resulted in some timeout for Jupyter. Simply install `Cbc` in Julia REPL. Moreover, what do you mean by "I have tried using ] build IJulia but it doesn't work."

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel My guess is that they probably saw `]build IJulia` as a solution for kernel crash in some other question, where the problem was related to IJulia installation, and tried it in case it helped. Here the problem is likely different, like you have mentioned.

Comment: @Sundar you do not have "one fits all" answer to system crashes ;p